# I have a basic ms access question about a relationship between 3 tables

Tags: ms-access, database-design, relationship

I have 3 tables

1. `ITEMS` - PK = Item# - contains item details
2. `ORDERS` - PK = Order# - contains order summaries
3. `TRANSACTIONS` - PK = Transaction# - Contains a breakdown of multiple transactions that make up an order

They all have an `Item#` column.

I have a one-to-many relationship from `items.item#` to `orders.item#`.

My question is: should the relationship to `Transactions` be from `Items.Item#` to `Transactions.Item#`, or from `Orders.order#` to `transactions.order#`?

Thanks

Comment: From both. Relationship is actually many-to-many. Each order can have multiple items and each item can associate with multiple orders. Transactions is a "junction" table that associates multiple items with each order. Advise you not use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Better would be OrderNum or OrderNo. Also, not all UPPERCASE letters, CamelCase is better as it is easier to read. I would change name of Transactions to OrderDetails.

Comment: So let me clarify a many to many between items and orders and a many to many between items and transactions ?

Comment: I think I understand, a junction between items and orders and a junction between orders and transactions. is that correct? or is there a third junction between items and transactions as well ?

Comment: It is a many-to-many between Items and Orders. Transactions table is the junction between Items and Orders. Items and Orders are both related to Transactions by key fields. This is how Items and Orders are associated - through Transactions. Each record in Transactions must have OrderID and ItemID as foreign keys and each pair should be unique. Basic RDBMS concept. At least, I made an assumption that items are what "make up an order".

Comment: Orders are made up of items. Now it makes sense, every example I looked at simply stopped at creating the junction and didn't explain HOW it was used. Thanks again!